# Реализация  парсера в gevent/greenlet

Tags: python

Имеется код наподобие:

```
g = Grab()
g.go('mysite.ru')
link = g.puquery('.selector').text()
g.go(link)
for i in g.puquery('.selector'):
    result = puQuery('a').text()
    print result
```

**Как можно реализовать подобный или схожий парсер на gevent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gevent` это библиотека для асинхронного ввода/вывода. [`pyquery`](http://pythonhosted.org//pyquery/#quickstart) позволяет jquery-запросы на уже скачанных xml/html документах исполнять.